# Measurement of black region in binary image

Tags: image, image-segmentation

[image]

I am trying to measure the length of the black region after segmentation.
I have a large set of images where the final result after segmentation is a black region that is usually above the white region. I want to write code to automatically measure the length of the black region in pixels, from the lowest point to the top.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: There are many ways to define a measurement like this. For example, you could either 1) Measure the area of the black region. 2) Measure the length/width of the minimum rectangle that can contain the black region. 3) Measure the radius of the minimum enclosing circle. There are many other formalizations. Can you pick a specific formal definition that you want to use?

Comment: Hi Nick, Thank you for your reply. I would only like to measure the black region in the red circle. Is there a way to write code to specifically measure the length of this specific black region? I want to measure the length in pixels, like drawing a line from the bottom to the top of the black region and measuring the length in pixels

Comment: Without worrying about code, how would you tell someone which black object you want to measure? Just in straight English. And also, what aspect of it do you want to measure? Width? Height? Longest diagonal?